# Try/catch not catching 500 error on CloudPage

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I have a CodeResource CloudPage that contains only SSJS that is wrapped in one big try/catch, like this:

```
<script language="javascript" runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");

try {
<a bunch of ssjs code>
} catch(e) {
Write("An error occurred. ");
}
</script>
```

Inside the try/catch I'm performing operations like looping through data extension rows, upserting into data extensions, making http requests and parsing responses. There is nothing else on the page.
I probably have some faulty data that from time to time ends up crashing the script and I am trying to find out what exactly is happening, but despite the try/catch block all I get on the page is the 500 Internal server error. What could be the cause?

Comment: Do you have an orphaned bracket within your SSJS? Also, it might be more helpful to post that section of your solution in order to get a detailed answer.

Comment: With Jason on this, most likely a bracket issue. You could try eslint with https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-ssjs (removing the <> tags) which could help detect the issue:)